# How to send a data from one client to another client?

Tags: c#, tcp, client, voip

I have already created my own VOIP server and client using pure sockets. All clients can send voice data to the server and server receives the audio data fine and plays it in real time; but what if the client wants to communicate to a specific client? How do I do that?

**Edit: For example client A connects to C (which is the server) and client B connects to C. How can A send data to B with or without sending data to C?**

**P.S.I can show my code if it is needed. Or if I am not being specific just tell me and I will elaborate more on my question.**

Comment: You are asking a whole design. I think you should narrow down your scope of questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `A` connects to `C`
- `B` connects to `C`
- `A` asks `C` if `B` is available
- `C` checks that he can communicate with B
- if so

  - `A` send data to `C` by saying *it's for `B`*
  - `C` transfers data to `B`
- if not

  - `A` tries later to asks `C` if `B` is available

Comment: Thanks I think this will work perfectly. I will post another question with some source code if I have problem doing this method.

Comment: very good if you want double the data transfered overall and the transmission time + eating some cpu time of the server

Comment: @L.B: I assumed, as @DanielLopez calls `C` a server and `A`, `B` clients, that all data exchange **must** go through the server. But if `A` can directly talk to `B`, it's maybe better to do it. Can't advise on the best choice here, it would need more description on the project.

Comment: @Otiel Here is the question `How can A send data to B with or without sending data to C`

Answer (score 1):

Your server can work as an orchestrator. `A` can request `Client B's IP & listening port` from your server and then connect to that address directly.

Comment: I am using TcpListener and TcpClient, how can I request the IP address from a TcpClient object?

Comment: @DanielLopez: Ask a new question for that.

Comment: You should implement a higher level protocol. Such as  messages (e.g, a serialized class) `asking a client's info` , `returning info` , `sends voice data` etc. I thinks you should read some docs about RPC. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_procedure_call